# How to change Managed Package publisher name

Tags: managed-package

I created a manage package in my developer org and when I install that package in another developer org, it show the publisher name as "Gmail". But in my personal information, company name is something else. I want to know where does it get the publisher name and how to change it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change that in the company profile (organization name) this should do the trick.

Comment: But what if the Package is already created, changing the company name doesnt do the trick. It is still picking up the old publisher name. Seems like the Publisher name is already stored in the package somewhere, when the package was first created.

Comment: @user2387 give it a few hours to synchronize

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Organization Name under "Company Profile" to display the name of the publisher. Sometimes, it takes some time to reflect where the Managed Package is installed, but it definitely works.