# How do I change the publisher name for a Beta or Managed package?

Tags: managed-package, beta-managed-package

According to an [old question/answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3320/how-to-change-managed-package-publisher-name) from 6 years ago  the publisher name comes from the `Company Information`, but this is not the case for me, as the company name is set in the `company information` profile, but the name is not appearing on my packages. So perhaps the answer is out of date.

How do I change publisher name for a Beta or Managed package?